# get a command process back after closing a session

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Arrrgh!  I'm using one of those drop down shells (guake, I think) on Linux.

I'm dd-ing an SD card, and I accidentilly closed the shell session that was running that command.  The light is still blinking on the card, but I want to get that shell session back so I can see confirmation that the process completed correctly...Any ideas?

Comment: Check if your command still running with `ps`. Normally the process will abort when shell closes.

Comment: The blinking may well be the cache flushing to the card, rather than dd still writing.

Answer (score 0):

You could trace writes with `strace -s1024 -e $(pgrep dd)` or so. There are also tools which sniff on tty's; the most obvious would by `ttysnoop`, which is available on Ubuntu via package.